# Removing a line boundary form a half disk

Tags: general-topology

Let's cut a disk in two halves. Take one of the two halves. Its boundary is made of two pieces: one is the half circle and the other is "the line boundary" along the cut. I was told that  the half disk minus its "line boundary" is not a manifold but if instead of removing the line boundary we remove an entire neighborhood of it then we get a manifold with boundary. Thank you for explaining this to me!!

Comment: It is manifold with boundary in both cases.

Comment: I guess it also depends in the precise definition of "line boundary": if the end points are not included, then indeed the complement is not a manifold with boundary.

Comment: Do you mind clarifying your question (by defining properly what is the "line boundary")? Otherwise, you will not get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: The half disk has a boundary that is composed of a half a circle and a line segment joining the two endpoints of the half circle. This line segment is what I called the line boundary.

Comment: This definition not good enough: You still have to decide if the endpoints are included in the line segment or not (see my comment above). The answer to your question depends on this.